# Calculating mean and standard deviation in R in one column depending on factors in other columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mean, calculated-columns, standard-deviation

I would like to calculate the mean and the standard deviation from the data in the "skada" column that are depending in three other columns. My table looks like this: [image]

The "geografi" column have the categorical variables: **SV, NV, M, SO, SV**

The "gradering" column have the categorical variables: **1, 2**

The "plats" column have the categorical variables: **20m, kant**

In other words, this means I would have the mean and standard deviation for SV,1,20m; SV,2,20m; SV,1,kant; SV,2,kant; NV,1,20m,...... and so forth. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this easily?

Cheers!

Comment: picture is not a reproducible example

Comment: type `?data.table` or look at `dplyr`'s `group_by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data.table:

```
library(data.table) 

setDT(data)[, list(skada_mean = mean(skada), skada_sd = sd(skada)), 
                 by = c("geografi", "gardering", "plats")]
```

or dyplr:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
    group_by(geografi, gardering, plats) %>% 
    summarise(skada_mean = mean(value), skada_sd = sd(value))
```

Comment: Thank you so much gcons. I tried the data.table and it worked just perfectly. No more excel when it comes to massive tables from now on.